# Local minima of the distance metric on algebraic manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, geodesic

Let $M$ be an algebraic manifold.  Let $P:[0,1]\rightarrow M$ be a finite length $C^\infty$ path on $M$.  Let $d_M(x,y)$ indicate the shortest length geodesic from $x$ to $y$ on $M$.

Let $s\in M$ be some point on $M$.  Consider a function $f_s:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$f_s(t) = d_M(s,P(t))$$

Does $f_s(t)$ have a bounded number of local minima for any given $s$, $P$, and $M$?

Any results that might be useful in proving this or counterexamples would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $f_s$ may certainly be constant. Take $P$ to be a small geodesic circle in $M$ centered at $s$. By the way, since you're using $x$ for a point of $M$, I'd be happier if you used $t\in [0,1]$ as the independent variable for $P$.

Comment: I changed the variable to $t$.  $f_s$ can be constant producing a single local minimum.  Alternately, $P$ and/or $M$ can be extremely curved producing many local minima (consider $M = \mathbb{R}^2$, $s = (0,-1000)$, $P = 100*\sin(100*x)$).  I'm interested in coming up with a bound on the number of local minima of $f_s$ in terms of the dimensionality of $M$, the degree/number of polynomials defining $M$ and the number of inflections of $P$ (or the degree of $P$ if we assume $P$ is a polynomial).

Comment: Ordinarily, when you speak of a local extremum it's a point in the *domain*. So a constant function has (very) infinitely many minima/maxima.